# Standard notation for isometry group?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

Let $M$ be a (semi) Riemannian manifold, is there a standard notation for the group of isometries on $M$?  I would think $\mathrm{ISO}(M)$ would be appropriate, but I've never encountered a dedicated notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\operatorname{Iso}(M)$ (or usually $\operatorname{Iso}(M,g)$ making the metric explicit) is very common.

Comment: And you even find $\operatorname{ISO}(M)$ with all caps make an appearance here and there.

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  Would you mind pointing out one or two references that use this notation?  I'm a theoretical physics grad student, so my familiarity with math literature where I can find stuff like this is a bit limited.  Thanks again.

Comment: @joshphysics: my usual reference is Petersen's "Riemannian Geometry", which uses this notation. It isn't universal - e.g. I just checked Lee's "Riemannian Manifolds..." and O'Neill's "Semi-Riemannian Geometry..." to find they use  $\mathscr I(M,g)$ and $I(M,g)$ respectively.

Comment: Isom(M) is also very common.